# I always end up with mixed line-endings in Atom

Tags: atom-editor, line-endings

I have a package installed ([Line Ending Selector](https://github.com/atom/line-ending-selector)) which can tell me what line endings (LF or CRLF or Mixed) are used in a file.

By default it's LF (which is my preferred one), but during the editing procedure it sometimes becomes Mixed and then I always have to set it back to LF manually.

It's very annoying when I forget to set all line-endings back to LF, push a file onto Github with Mixed line endings, someone pulls it, pushes their changes, and half of that commit are just line-ending changes that their editor made to the file because it has automatic line-ending correction - not like mine.

Can Atom also have this functionality? Is there a way to ensure that (for example on save) all line endings of a file are set to LF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `.gitattributes` to deal with line-endings:

```
    # Set the default behavior, in case people don't have core.autocrlf set.
    * text=auto

    # Explicitly declare text files you want to always be normalized and converted
    # to native line endings on checkout.
    *.c text
    *.h text

    # Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout.
    *.sln text eol=crlf

    # Denote all files that are truly binary and should not be modified.
    *.png binary
    *.jpg binary
```

**Related:** [GitHub User Documentation: Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/)

Alternatively, you can use [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) to achieve the same. It's especially useful to enforce consistent settings across teams or open-source contributors.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer because it's more general

Answer (score 0):

I've found a package ([Force Line Endings](https://atom.io/packages/force-line-endings)) that does exactly what I need. I wonder why others are not having this same problem, and why this package has so few downloads.